# Add Index on field of AbstractClass

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have created one abstract model which provides default timestamp and I want to create Index on the field declared in that model

**Parent Model**

```
class CommonModel(models.Model):
    """
        Provides default timestamp model
    """
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

**Child Model**

```
class User(CommonModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=False, null=False)
    work_email = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=False, null=False)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False, null=False)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'user'
```

I want to apply index on *created_at* field

P.S: I'm using django==2.0.5, djangorestframework==3.8.2, python 3.6.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the index using the [`indexes` [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#indexes) (was introduced in django==1.11 so it will work for you) attribute in the `Meta` class:

```
class EBUser(CommonModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=False, null=False)
    work_email = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=False, null=False)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False, null=False)
    
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'user'
        indexes = [
            models.Index(fields=['created_at'], name='created_at_idx'),
        ]
```

Comment: After declaring indexes the migration generated is listed below and for some reason it doesn't mention all the models in project



class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    operations = [
        migrations.AddIndex(
            model_name='<model1>',
            index=models.Index(fields=['created_at'], name='created_at_idx'),
        ),  ]

Comment: @aMighty you other models are likely already created in the previous migration files.

Comment: Shouldn't it have the changes for indexes

Comment: @aMighty Why would other models change when you set an index on this model? Do note setting an index on `EBUser` does not mean you are setting an index on all models inheriting from `CommonModel`. If you want to do that have the index in the `Meta` of `CommonModel` and have the other models `Meta` inherit from it.